# Mask password with asterisk with install4j in console mode

Tags: install4j

I am using the latest version(9.0.4) of install4j. We have built an installer using install4j. Now there is a requirement where in console mode when the user enters password , it should be shown by asterisk or some other character.

Currently if the user enters something for password field, nothing is shown on console. In GUI mode dots are shown for each user key input.
I could not find out any setting in install4j to enable this for console mode.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that in Java. The method `java.io.Console.readPassword()` disables echoing, but it is not possible to configure an echo character like an asterisk.

Comment: Instead of asterisk , Can I configure other character like say "x" ?

Comment: No echo characters are available at all.